# requestUserTokenForDeveloperToken return error - MusicKit get userToken

Tags: objective-c, apple-music, apple-musickit

requestUserTokenForDeveloperToken return error

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    [self.cloudServiceController requestUserTokenForDeveloperToken:developerToken completionHandler:^(NSString * _Nullable userToken, NSError * _Nullable error) {

                            NSLog(@"userToken error - %@", error);

                        }];
                    }
```

Error:

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=7 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c105e870 {Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c105e180 {Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store, SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=401}}}}}
```

How can I solve this problem? Thx!

Comment: I'm getting an error `NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"` with this code.  It references the URL endpoint for `createMusicToken`.  Any ideas?

Comment: I believe I was getting the 999 error due to trying to send simultaneous SK requests.  I am still struggling with a 401 error though.  I've verified that the developer token I'm generating works with the Apple Music API, but it gets rejected in this call to `requestUserTokenForDeveloperToken`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem, the problem was in the developer token, it was not properly created. I recreated the token using this utility https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator and it all worked ;)

Comment: How exactly given URL works? Can you please explain in more detail

Comment: OMG, but why it's not said in the error message that developer token isn't valid? :-(